# constructor includeProperties for EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, expression

I have the following method in data access layer:

```
GetByFilterIncluding(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
```

Now I have to call it from business layer, including properties:

```
dll.GetByFilterIncluding(x => x.Id == id, x => x.Person, x => x.Address)
```

However, I want to call it like this:

```
if (needPerson) {
    includeProperties.Add((x => x.Person));
}
if (needAddress) {
    includeProperties = (x => x.Address);
}
dll.GetByFilterIncluding(x => x.Id == id, includeProperties)
```

I simply do not understand how to define `includeProperties` array/list?

**EDIT:**
As a note - I do not have access to Data access layer and I cannot change it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701046/combine-multiple-expression-as-a-lambda-for-partial-update-expressionfunct-o#comment84400800_48701046

Comment: Ok, if I do not have access to DAL level? I still have to convert list to array somehow,?

Comment: Yes, that was the point. Create list, `Add` conditionally in it and at the end call your method passing `list.ToArray()`. e.g. `var includeProperties = new List<Expression<Func<YourEntity, object>>>(); if (..) includeProperties.Add(...); dll.GetByFilterIncluding(x => x.Id == id, includeProperties.ToArray())`

Comment: Then you can mark this as Duplicate or move your comment to answer, I will mark your answer.

Comment: I can't because the other question has no answer (just comment like here). Glad it helped, let move on.